# How to store only limited number of docs in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I will be collecting data for every 10sec and hence my size of the particular index will be growing. So 
1. Is there any way to limit the storage. I.e at any point of time i may require the latest 100 docs.count

Comment: Why not delete older entries?

Comment: okay, even to do that how to delete the old entries? is there any option to verify and delete the old docs of particular index in golang?

Comment: I tried to delete the 2000 docs of particular index. It got deleted but when i try to list then i am able to see the docs count unchanged...

Comment: root@kishan> curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/cscfcounter/cscfcounter/_delete_by_query?routing=1&pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "size" : 2000,
  "sort" : [
        { "date" : {"order" : "asc"}}
    ]
  
}'
{
  "took" : 61,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "total" : 3,
  "deleted" : 3,
  "batches" : 1,
  "version_conflicts" : 0,
  "noops" : 0,
  "retries" : {
    "bulk" : 0,
    "search" : 0
  },
  "throttled_millis" : 0,
  "requests_per_second" : -1.0,
  "throttled_until_millis" : 0,
  "failures" : [ ]
}

Comment: root@kishan> curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v&pretty'
health status index             uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
green  open   cscfcounter       MWNXpegeTuacRlK2bMpbHg   5   1      20943            0     11.6mb          5.8mb